# data reader is not reading the data from the table

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0

I am using the data reader to show specific column data into grid view. Actually i want to get the last day record from table.

```
 DateTime yestarday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            string query = "select NAME,CLOSING_READING,RATE  from CASHSALE_DETAIL where DATE = '" + yestarday + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = Conn;
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                CashSaleVoucherGridView.Rows.Add(num, "", dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["CLOSING_READING"].ToString(), "", "", "", dr["RATE"].ToString());
                num++;
            }
```

On above given query data reader returns me 0 record.
Any Suggstions????

Comment: DateTime is with the milliseconds (oups, not with Today), use BETWEEN syntax and a Date format.

Comment: run the same query in sql and see if it returns any value.

Comment: by the way, try using a parametrized query `WHERE DATE between @d1 and @d2`, and add paramaters to the SqlCommand

Answer (score 0):

the issue is on this statement

```
string query = "select NAME,CLOSING_READING,RATE  from CASHSALE_DETAIL where DATE = '" + yestarday + "'";
```

use parameterized command

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);

string query = "select NAME,CLOSING_READING,RATE  from CASHSALE_DETAIL where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, DATE )) = DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, @yesterday))";


SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesterday", yesterday);
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: `Where DATE = BETWEEN @yesterday AND @today`  IS this work for you ?

Comment: no it isn't, i thought that he needs the records from yesterday to today.

Answer (score 0):

First check if your select query it its returning records then
add dr.HasRows to check your data reader return rows or not

```
DateTime yesterday = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
string query = "select NAME,CLOSING_READING,RATE  from CASHSALE_DETAIL where DATE = @date";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = Conn;
cmd.CommandText = query;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", yesterday );
SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
if (dr.HasRows)
{
     while (dr.Read())
            {
                CashSaleVoucherGridView.Rows.Add(num, "", dr["NAME"].ToString(), dr["CLOSING_READING"].ToString(), "", "", "", dr["RATE"].ToString());
                num++;
            }
}
else
{
//Throw error ("No rows found.");
}
```

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

You can format the date field like this

> ```
> string query = "select NAME,CLOSING_READING,RATE  from CASHSALE_DETAIL
> where convert(varchar(15),DATE,101)= '" + yestarday + "'";
> ```

but the method mentioned by @BizApps and @mdcuesta like below is very less erroneous

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yesterday", yesterday);
```